# Are css table columns being rendered sequentially no matter what?

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools

With the Chrome devtools and 6x cpu throttling I tracked down a jumping content box to the Chrome browser quite literally not containing the last table column in the html document yet. It simply isn't there yet. So my question is, if I reimplement the layout of the site with divs, can I expect that this would be solved? Or could the browser still decide that one particular div that happens to be responsible for my rightcolumn gets rendered very last and therefore my users will see the middle column resizing itself for a split second.
In theory it's nice that the browser is "incrementally" rendering the page.. but this feels more like sequential rendering when the middle column (for a tiny split second) renders across the whole right side until the browser is deciding to also render the right column.

[image: html document with no rightcolumn yet]

1. Can someone confirm that this is inherent with table layouts?
2. And that it would not happen in a block/flex/grid layout?

Because this certainly isn't nice for the user who sees a flash of content and css reflow.
At first I thought that this could be solved by making the rightcolumn smaller (byte-wise) so the browser gets to it sooner but even a completely empty rightcolumn gets deferred enough for there to be a noticeable reflow. I could not see this problem in Firefox so this might be a Chrome implementation issue. If anyone has any official Chrome dev links where their developers confirm that this is how they render tables, that would be amazing.

Comment: Please provide code as text, not as a picture of text.

Comment: That looks like an actual `table` element, not what is generally referred to as a CSS table, which is the use of `display: table` and associated `display` values on other elements. If all of the HTML is provided at once to the browser, there's no reason the it wouldn't render all of the columns, unless there was CSS which told it not to (the column had a `display: none` which was later removed). You can ensure consistent rendering by using `table-layout: fixed`, but that may or may not work for your situation.

Comment: Unless you use a `fixed` table layout, the browser needs to know the contents of _all_ cells in a “column”, before it can determine, how wide to make this column. And if it has to size _all_ columns dynamically, to divide a given table element width between them, then it needs to know the content of _all_ cells in _all_ columns first. That is inherent in how the table layout algorithm works.

Comment: this is not really a question for css/web developers, more for the chrome browser developer who can confirm how their table rendering works in combination with partially parsed html

Comment: You might have better luck on https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-discuss?pli=1 or some other venue devoted to Chrome/Chromium development. But they're going to want a [mre] just as much as answerers on Stack Overflow. More so, I would think.